# How should I select a colored line in a picture using Python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have some images with lines of specific colors on varied backgrounds. In short, I'm trying to do this:

1. Load image into program
2. Search image for line of color #FFFFFF
3. Generate an array of X,Y pixel coordinates
4. Generate an "if" statement for values above and below that line.

So what I need help with is how I can accomplish point "b", I've been reading docs and examples for PIL and Pillow, but I have yet to find something dealing specifically with this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is something like this what you are looking for?

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('a.png')
width, height = img.size

for y in range(0, height):
    if img.getpixel((1, y)) == (255, 255, 255):
        print "White line on Y == {}".format(y)
```

Edit:
Here is a better way.

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('a.png')
pixels = list(im.getdata())
width, height = im.size

pixels = [pixels[i * width:(i + 1) * width] for i in xrange(height)]

for idx, y in enumerate(pixels):
    if y[0] == (255, 255, 255):
        print "Line {} is white.".format(idx)
```

Comment: This looks right, I will not be able to test it fully until tomorrow. I'll leave this open in the mean time. Thanks for the quick answer.